# How to both pivot a table and assign event aligned IDs

Tags: r, pivot-table

I need to accomplish 2 task that might be best handled at the same time.  I need to pivot a simple table but while pivoting I need to normalize one of the columns like almost like a rank value.  Say we start with a table of unit sales by date and event.  Not all events happen at same time.  What we want to do it compare unit sales across events not on date but by the relative date the event happened.  In the process the Month become meaningless.  So with a raw data table like:

```
 dfr <- data.frame(
  Event = c("A","B","A","C","A","B","C"),
  Month  = c("Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Mar","Mar","Mar"),
  Units = c(5,10,10,15,12,8,18)
  )
```

I need a resulting pivoted table like:

```
Row | A  | B  | C

1   | 5  | 10 | 15

2   | 10 | 8  | 18

3   | 12 | na | na
```

I assume I could put each event into its own vector the just merge the vectors but it seems like there should be a cleaner way that would also handle the na situations.

Comment: isnt a pivot table something excel made up? you've posted this in the r section of stack overflow. There is no r code or attempt to further prove my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
df$indx <- with(df, ave(seq_along(Event), Event, FUN=seq_along))
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, indx~Event, value.var='Units')
#   indx  A   B   C 
#1    1   5  10  15
#2    2  10   8  18
#3    3  12  NA  NA
```

Or

```
 xtabs(Units~indx+Event, df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the tabulation part with `tidyr`.  Needs NA handling though.

```
library(tidyr)

dfr <- data.frame(
  Event = c("A","B","A","C","A","B","C"),
  Month  = c("Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Mar","Mar","Mar"),
  Units = c(5,10,10,15,12,8,18)
  )

pivot <- spread(dfr[,-2],Event,Units)
pivot
```